# Time out from one network

Tags: networking, debian, linux-networking, ethernet

I have a very strange case

We have a server with several IPs.
For example:
AA.AA.AA.AA;
AA.AA.AA.AB;
AA.AA.AA.AC;
AA.AA.AA.AD;
AA.AA.AA.AE;
.
.
.
And additional from another pool: SS.SS.SS.SS

Pages and this server display correctly from all ISPs except one.
With this particular ISP we get time out for all IPs. On all devices on the network. Pings are back but the webpage do not open. With other service / ports (21,25,587,25,465) is also a problem.

Iptables are clean (even if this isp provides dynamic IP)

It looks like the connection was sitting on the firewall/blacklist.

Is there a way to verify who is guilty? Is it a server company or internet provider? Maybe the problem lies entirely elsewhere?

The server works with debian 8.8 + bind9 + apache2 + fail2ban (when it is disabled identically)

Please help and apologize for my english

Answer (score 0):

Run a traceroute to find out where the connection is being dropped

Comment: In traceroute everything looks ok

traceroute to website_on_server.com (IP_MY_SERVER), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  6.904 ms  7.662 ms  7.658 ms
 8  172.17.28.238 (172.17.28.238)  17.700 ms  17.676 ms 172.17.28.198 (172.17.28.198)  16.619 ms
 9  * * *
10  91.121.131.24 (91.121.131.24)  17.696 ms  17.681 ms  17.670 ms
12  be100-1102.fra-1-a9.de.eu (213.251.128.113)  29.262 ms  29.141 ms *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * sXX.my_server.com (IP_MY_SERVER)  47.031 ms *